# Subset Sum Problem (general)

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I have a problem which turned to be similar to the Subset Sum Problem. The main differences between the Subset Sum Problem and my problem are:
1- The vector elements can be positive and negative (in my readings on Subset Sum Problem, I've found that all the discussion related to non-negative integers).
2- The vector elements in my case are real (non-integer).

So, I am asking if my problem is also a subset sum problem? if so, can we use the proposed solutions to solve my problem?
If not, where should I look for similar problems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is a subset sum problem. But the pseudo-polynomial time algorithm does no longer work since the numbers are not integers.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any article that discuss this problem?